# Cast a list column into dummy columns in Python Polars?

Tags: python-polars

I have a very large data frame where there is a column that is a list of numbers representing category membership.

Here is a dummy version

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

segments = [str(i) for i in range(1_000)]

# My real data is ~500m rows
nums = np.random.choice(segments, (100_000,10))

df = pd.DataFrame({'segments': [','.join(n) for n in nums]})
```

| userId | segments |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 885,106,49,138,295,254,26,460,0,844 |
| 1 | 908,709,454,966,151,922,666,886,65,708 |
| 2 | 664,713,272,241,301,498,630,834,702,289 |
| 3 | 60,880,906,471,437,383,878,369,556,876 |
| 4 | 817,183,365,171,23,484,934,476,273,230 |
| ... | ... |

Note that there is a known list of segments (0-999 in the example)

I want to cast this into dummy columns indicating membership to each segment.

I found a few ways of doing this:

In `pandas`:

```
df_one_hot_encoded = (df['segments']
    .str.split(',')
    .explode()
    .reset_index()
    .assign(__one__=1)
    .pivot_table(index='index', columns='segments', values='__one__', fill_value=0)
)
```

(takes 8 seconds on a 100k row sample)

And `polars`

```
df2 = pl.from_pandas(df[['segments']])
df_ans = (df2
          .with_columns([
              pl.arange(0, len(df2)).alias('row_index'), 
              pl.col('segments').str.split(','), 
              pl.lit(1).alias('__one__')
          ])
          .explode('segments')
          .pivot(index='row_index', columns='segments', values='__one__')
          .fill_null(0)
     )
df_one_hot_encoded = df_ans.to_pandas()
```

(takes 1.5 seconds inclusive of the conversion to and from pandas,  .9s without)

However, I hear .pivot is not efficient, and that it does not work well with lazy frames.

I tried other solutions in `polars`, but they were much slower:

```
_ = df2.lazy().with_columns(**{segment: pl.col('segments').str.contains(segment) for segment in segments}).collect()
```

(2 seconds)

```
(df2
 .with_columns([
     pl.arange(0, len(df2)).alias('row_index'), 
     pl.col('segments').str.split(',')
 ])
 .explode('segments')
 .to_dummies(columns=['segments'])
 .groupby('row_index')
 .sum()
)
```

(4 seconds)

Does anyone know a better solution than the .9s pivot?

Answer (score 1):

This approach ends up being slower than the pivot but it's a got a different trick so I'll include it.

```
df2=pl.from_pandas(df)
df2_ans=(df2.with_row_count('userId').with_column(pl.col('segments').str.split(',')).explode('segments') \
    .with_columns([pl.when(pl.col('segments')==pl.lit(str(i))).then(pl.lit(1,pl.Int32)).otherwise(pl.lit(0,pl.Int32)).alias(str(i)) for i in range(1000)]) \
    .groupby('userId')).agg(pl.exclude('segments').sum())
df_one_hot_encoded = df2_ans.to_pandas()
```

A couple of other observations.  I'm not sure if you checked the output of your `str.contains` method but I would think that wouldn't work because, for example, 15 is contained within 154 when looking at strings.

The other thing, which I guess is just a preference, is the `with_row_count` syntax vs the `pl.arrange`.  I don't think the performance of either is better (at least not significantly so) but you don't have to reference the df name to get the `len` of it which is nice.

I tried a couple other things that were also worse including not doing the explode and just doing `is_in` but that was slower.  I tried using bools instead of 1s and 0s and then aggregating with `any` but that was slower.

Comment: Note that `pl.arange` accepts `pl.count`.